# CSS, min-width not working in Compatability Mode

Tags: css

I am using a drop down menu for a website and in IE8 it works just fine, but when I go into compatability mode the drop down menu looks wrong. The background color is only as wide as the text in each list element. Here is a image of the issue.

[image]

Here is how it looks in IE8, which is the correct way:

[image]

The one css property that doesnt seem to work in compatibility mode is the min-width, which Im assuming compatibility mode is an older version of IE? Or at least I am assuming this issue would happen in IE7. Here is the css property for this menu:

```
#main_menu li ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    border:no-border;
}

#main_menu li ul li {
    float:none;
    display:inline;
}

#main_menu li ul li a {
    background:#efefef;
    color:#24313C;
    text-align:left;
    text-transform:none;
    font-weight:normal;
    letter-spacing:normal;
    min-width:70px;
}
```

Any idea how to get the older version if IE to work like how it looks in IE8?

**EDIT:**
Here is the image when adding display:block and width:70px. As you can see it cuts off, trying to have it automatically expand to the longest text in the menu like it would in IE8.

[image]

Comment: So are you worried that it will display incorrectly in IE7 or are you worried someone might switch to compatibility mode and it will look wrong?

Comment: Im worried it will display incorrectly for older versions of IE. I need to at least support IE7 and above.

Comment: Could you post a link to the site or a jsfiddle.net? It is easier to work with the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What will probably work best is to detect the widest element using JavaScript, then set the elements to that width - see jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/NneMQ/). I checked in IE7 and it works as far as I understand your requirements.

The jQuery I used was:

```
    $(function () {
        var target = $('#main_menu li ul li');
        var target_array = [];
        target.each(function (i) {
            target_array[i] = $(this).width();
        });
        // get widest element and add 10px of padding on the right
        var max_width = Math.max.apply(null, target_array)+10; 
        target.find('a').css( { 'width': max_width + 'px', 'display': 'block' } );

    });
```

**EDIT:**

Good catch. I updated the code to work with multiple lists. It works in IE7 and in IE8 compatibility mode (which is designed to emulate IE7 anyway):

See http://jsfiddle.net/g_thom/NneMQ/1/

Updated jQuery:

```
    var target = $('#main_menu > li');
    var target_array = [];
    target.each(function (i) {
        $(this).find('li').each(function (j) {
            target_array[j] = $(this).width();
        });
        // get widest element and add right padding of 10 px
        var max_width = Math.max.apply(null, target_array)+10;
        target.eq(i).find('a').css( { 'width': max_width + 'px', 'display': 'block' } );
    });
```

Comment: Does this work for multiple lists? There are multiple drop down lists, will this grab the widest from all of them together? Or does it treat each list separately?

Comment: Actually that affects the parent list. Its a drop down list and the drop down portion is the one Im trying to auto adjust. Each list are contained in #main_menu li ul li. I tried changing your list var target = $('#main_menu > li'); to var target = $('#main_menu li > ul'); but when I do that it still does the original issue, where it uses the longest length for all drop down lists, it doesnt find each one individually. For example drop down list one longest is applied to the second drop down list as well.

Comment: I think I'd need to see more of the code at this point, as otherwise, I'd just be guessing what your structure is. Can post a jsfiddle or dev version of your page?

Comment: Hi John - I made some tweaks - this worked for me in compatibility mode: http://jsfiddle.net/BppgV/5/

Comment: Looks like it doesnt work unless I remove this line: behavior:url('css/PIE.htc'); Drats. I needed to use that. I didnt add that in the jsfiddle

Comment: I think I might be challenged to help you here. I can't see your code, and it seems it keeps failing b/c of factors I'm not aware of. If you like the solution in general and are looking for an alternative to CSSPie, http://selectivizr.com/ might be worth your while.

Answer (score 0):

Use width instead of min-width and add display: block; to the style:

```
#main_menu li ul li a {
    display: block;
    background:#efefef;
    color:#24313C;
    text-align:left;
    text-transform:none;
    font-weight:normal;
    letter-spacing:normal;
    width:70px;
}
```

Comment: I just did that and doesnt work. Look at my original post, I updated it with a new image of the changes you suggested.

Comment: Try removing the width:70px; altogether. It should will stretch to ill the li it's contained in then with display: block;

Comment: If I remove width and just have display:block then the original image/issue happens.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but try doing something similar to this:

```
#main_menu li ul li a {
    display: block;
    background:#efefef;
    color:#24313C;
    text-align:left;
    text-transform:none;
    font-weight:normal;
    letter-spacing:normal;
    min-width:70px;
    width:auto !important;
    width: 70px;
}
```

I think that will make IE work :D